# How to add a block element (position: absolute) under an active/hover li item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li ><a class="active" href="http://google.com">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="asdasdasd">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I need to add a block element **on hover** and **a.class="active"**

The element should be a span e.g. something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#link1"><span class="arrow"></span>Link 1</a></li><!-- hovering this link -->
    <li ><a class="active" href="http://google.com"><span class="arrow"></span>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="asdasdasd">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to accomplish such task via jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `.wrapInner()` jQuery method that will help.

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('ul li').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).find('a').text();
            $(this).find('a').html('<span class="arrow"></span>'+text);
        });     
    });

</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li ><a class="active" href="http://google.com">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="asdasdasd">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and for `hover` use

```
$('ul li a').hover(function()
{
   $('ul li').find('a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

what above code do is remove `active class` on `hove` and add it to hovered `DOM`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you created the element, say `<span>`, and initially made it `display:none`, then with jQuery you can simply use `show()` and `hide()`, like so:

```
if specific element is being hovered over:
   $("#insertedSpan").show();
   $(this).find('a').html('<span class="arrow"></span>');
else
   $("#insertedSpan").hide();
```

Comment: but, I need to somehow insert this code `<span class="arrow"></span>` between the anchor tag, that is hovering or active. How to do that?

Comment: @user1394965 don't you think doing so replace text inside links too..?

Answer (score 0):

First you should set your 'li' position to 'relative'. Then add the  with display hidden. Then on hover of the a element, set display to block with jquery. And dont forget that your span position should be 'absolute';